# coredata int32 in text no show?

Tags: swiftui

I use core data to store something,and state it as

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject var exeplan: Explan
```

Explan is a entity

```
ForEach(Array(exeplan.exercisearray.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (index,item) in
Button(action: {
           item.duration -= 15
       do {
         try viewContext.save()
      } catch {} }, label: {
        Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")})
    Text("\(item.duration)")
     Button(action: {item.duration += 15
           do {
          try viewContext.save()
           } catch {})
```

the text Text("(item.duration)") is no update immediately, and it's an Int32 style,

but when I print it, the num is a new one. also when I navigate back

and I use another int32 to replace it, it has changed。

I mean it's a closure, and how can I pass a new array to replace it?
of another way, it fixes this problem?

Comment: Maybe explain what Explan is?

Comment: Explan is an entity  @Joakim Danielson

Comment: there are a lot of missing parts in your code that makes helping you difficult.

What's an entity?

Could you show us the code for Explan and item.

You show `@StateObject var exeplan: Explan`, maybe it should be 
`@StateObject var exeplan = Explan()`, or more likely, `@ObservedObject var exeplan: Explan`.

You could try to "manually" update the Explan, by adding 
`objectWillChange.send()` just before `item.duration -= 15`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to "manually" state update the Explan, by adding

```
exeplan.objectWillChange.send()
```

just before

```
item.duration -= 15
```